# Adding strike-through feature to certain cells in Table

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that creates a certain number of cells based on the number a user enters into a text box.  I am trying to get it so that when the "Shade even Rows" button is clicked, every other cell gets a line-through, but am not having luck.  I feel like using i % 2 === 0 is the right way to get the cells I want to put a line-through, but not sure of the specific parameters to put in.  Any suggestions would help!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nbrTxt').focus();

  function addItem() {

    var value = $('#nbrTxt').val();
    var usrName = prompt("Name?");
    $('#buttons').append('<li><button class="shade">Shade Even Rows</button><button class="drkLine">Show Dark Line Every 10 Rows</button></li>')

    for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
      $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      $('table tr:last td:first').html(i);
      $('table tr:last td:last').html(usrName);
      $(this).focus().select();
      $('#nbrTxt').val("");
    };
  };
  $('#btnGo').click(addItem);

  $('#nbrTxt').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13)
      addItem();
  })

  $(document).on('click', '.shade', function() {
    if (('#nbrTxt').val() % 2 === 0) {
      $(this).closest("tr").css('textDecoration' === 'iine-through');
    }
  })

});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<html>

<head>

  <title>JQuery Selector</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryselector.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>JQuery Selector</h1>
  Enter Number:
  <input type="number" name="nbrTxt" id="nbrTxt" />
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btnGo" />

  <div id='buttons'>

  </div>

  <table id="table" width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>No. Count</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: `'iine-through'`. I assume you meant `'line-through'`. Also, you clear out the value in `$('#nbrTxt').val("");`, so `if (('#nbrTxt').val() % 2 === 0)` can't work, not to mention you omitted the `$`.

Answer (score 1):

`.css('textDecoration' === 'iine-through');` is not valid procedure to set `css` property of element; see [`.css()`](http://api.jquery.com/css) .

Try using `:even` selector

```
$("tr:even").css("textDecoration", "line-through")
```

Comment: so like this?
 $(document).on('click', '.shade', function(){
  if($('#nbrTxt').val() % 2 === 0){
    $("tr:even").css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
   }
})

Comment: @Rassisland What is purpose of `$('#nbrTxt').val() % 2 === 0` ?

Comment: Oh, I guess I can get rid of that!  This is what I have now:
$(document).on('click', '#shade', function(){
  var shaded = $('tr:even').css('background', '#A0A0A0');
  $(shaded).toggle();
  })
I'm trying to have the shaded cells toggle from shaded to unshaded when the "Shade Rows" button is clicked, but the toggle is just removing the even cells.

Comment: Try storing existing `background` within a variable , removing `$(shaded).toggle();`

Comment: like this?  Sorry if these are easy questions, I'm new to coding!  I am really appreciating the help!
$(document).on('click', '#shade', function(){
  var shaded = ('background', '#A0A0A0')
  $('tr:even').css(shaded);
  })