# Shading a cell in a table when button is clicked

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a function that shades every other row in a cell, but can't figure out how to get it so when the button is clicked again, the cells get un-shaded. I'd also like it to not select the first row with the row headers.  Any ideas would be appreciated!

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nbrTxt').focus();

  function addItem() {

    var value = $('#nbrTxt').val();
    var usrName = prompt("Name?");


    for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
      $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      $('table tr:last td:first').html(i);
      $('table tr:last td:last').html(usrName);
      $(this).focus().select();
    };
  };
  $('#btnGo').click(addItem);

  $('#nbrTxt').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13)
      addItem();
  })

  $(document).on('click', '#shade', function() {
    $('tr:even').css('background', '#A0A0A0');
  })

  $(document).on('click', '#drkLine', function() {
    if ($('#nbrTxt').val() % 10 === 0) {
      ($('#nbrTxt').val()).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
    }
  })
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!doctype html>

<html>

<head>

  <title>JQuery Selector</title>

  <style type="text/css">
    body {
      font-family: Arial, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, sans-serif;
    }
  </style>

  <script src="jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="jqueryselector.js"></script>

</head>

<body>

  <h1>JQuery Selector</h1>
  Enter Number:
  <input type="number" name="nbrTxt" id="nbrTxt" />
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btnGo" />

  <div id='buttons'>
    <input type="button" value="Shade Even Rows" id="shade" />
    <input type="button" value="Show Dark Line Every 10 Rows" id="drkLine" />
  </div>

  <table id="table" width="500" border="1">
    <tr>
      <td>No. Count</td>
      <td>Name</td>
    </tr>
  </table>

</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34710641/adding-strike-through-feature-to-certain-cells-in-table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add class `shade` in your style and use `toggleClass()` function to `add/remove` it, check example bellow.

If you don't want to select the first row you can use `:not(:first-child)` :

```
$('tr:not(:first-child):even')
```

Hope this helps.

---

### Snippet

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#nbrTxt').focus();

  function addItem() {

    var value = $('#nbrTxt').val();
    var usrName = prompt("Name?");

    $('table>tbody').empty();
    for (var i = 1; i <= value; i++) {
      $('table').append('<tr><td></td><td></td></tr>');
      $('table tr:last td:first').html(i);
      $('table tr:last td:last').html(usrName);
      $(this).focus().select();
    };
  };
  $('#btnGo').click(addItem);

  $('#nbrTxt').keydown(function(e) {
    if (e.which === 13)
      addItem();
  })

  $(document).on('click', '#shade', function() {
    $('tr:not(:first-child):even').toggleClass('shade');
  })

  $(document).on('click', '#drkLine', function() {
    if ($('#nbrTxt').val() % 10 === 0) {
      ($('#nbrTxt').val()).css('textDecoration', 'line-through');
    }
  })
});
```

```css
tr.shade{
   background: #A0A0A0;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h1>JQuery Selector</h1>
  Enter Number:
  <input type="number" name="nbrTxt" id="nbrTxt" />
  <input type="button" value="GO" id="btnGo" />

  <div id='buttons'>
    <input type="button" value="Shade Even Rows" id="shade" />
    <input type="button" value="Show Dark Line Every 10 Rows" id="drkLine" />
  </div>

  <table id="table" width="500" border="1">
    <thead>      
      <tr>
          <td>No. Count</td>
          <td>Name</td>
      </tr>
    </thead>
  </table>
```

Comment: is there a way to select every tenth line?  I know the tr:even can only do every other, but is there something similar for every tenth line?  Thanks

Comment: No prob, yes you can, try to use `$('tr:nth-child(10n+10)')`.

Comment: thanks so much for the help! If I could ask one more thing, it would be great!  My only issue left is that when you click the GO button after it has already been clicked, it creates another table below the new table.  What could I add to the addItem function to make the GO button clear the first table and add new table on second click?

Comment: Glad i can help @Rassisland, you have just to add `$('table').empty();` before the for loop and it should work.

Comment: aweome!  I figured it would be something like that.  This clears my headers, too though.  Would that first-child code help with this?

Comment: I think the cleanest way is to put your header inside `thead` tag, then you can clear just tbody (that will be added dynamically), Check my update.